# SQL Server RECEIVE statement ordering issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, service-broker

I'm seeing some unexpected message ordering behavior running a `RECEIVE` statement against a Service Broker queue.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/receive-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> For a given conversation, a RECEIVE statement returns messages in ascending **message_sequence_number** order.

So I expect the messages in the queue to be returned in the order -1, 0, 1, 2, but they are actually returned in the order 0, 1, 2, -1. The returned order happen to match the order they were transmitted by the other party but not the message_sequence_number value. All the messages in the queue belong to the same conversation.

The negative message sequence number is an SB error message (`END CONVERSATION WITH ERROR` by the initiator). The same non-expected order also happens with a timer message (sequence -2). My understanding was that those error and timer message types would "skip ahead" in the queue and be dequeued first, but it's not what I'm seeing in practice. So my understanding and expectations must clearly be wrong, but I can't see what I'm missing.

I tested this on SQL Server 2019, 2017 and 2012 and the behavior is consistent between the versions. Is this just me not being able to grasp the docs?